# How can I force macports to fetch a port source from a specific url?

Tags: macos, macports

I'm editing and testing a package that I'd like to build via macports. Is there a way that I can force macports to fetch and build the package from my repository? I've edited my [Portfile](https://gist.github.com/ruipacheco/1c09035b330cdd6e138d95147a4bb45d) to point to a single repository but it seems to be ignoring it.

Comment: Are you running the `port install` command and that's what it ignores? If so then you'll likely need to edit `sources.conf` and specify the `URL` of your repo, before the `rsync` one.

Comment: I edited my Portfile to use a single URL and macports seems to ignore that.

Comment: It's probably using the `rsync` path in `sources.conf`, info here: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/development.local-repositories.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacPorts uses curl internally to download files, which gives you a couple of options to switch where stuff is downloaded from:

- You can use file:// URLs in the `master_sites` property of the Portfile to point to a local directory. Note that the fetch runs as the `macports` user, so make sure that user is allowed to read files from that directory.
- For file downloads, you can replace the cached file. MacPorts will use your replacement the next time it extracts the source code of a port. Run `port distfiles $portname` to find the local path where a file may be cached.
- You can switch to git for fetching by setting `fetch.type git`, `git.url` to whatever `git clone` will accept to clone your repository (which can be local) and optionally `git.branch` to a commitish you want to check out. See https://guide.macports.org/#reference.phases.fetch.git for details. Again, make sure that the `macports` user can read the local files if you use a local git repository.
- Any other version control system supported by MacPorts; see the guide for details.

Note that MacPorts caches file downloads by default (no caching is applied for version control systems at the moment), so if you did not modify the filename, you will have to run `sudo port clean --dist $portname` to delete the cache.

When building modified versions of ports, you'll also have to look out for a number of other points:

- MacPorts will download a precompiled binary if one is available. Since that precompiled binary will not match your modified Portfile or source code, pass the `-s` flag to `port` to force building from source.
- MacPorts will not compile a port if you run 'port install' and it is already installed (either activated or deactivated).

Probably the easiest solution to work around these two potential pitfalls is running `sudo port destroot $portname` instead of `sudo port install`. This will run all steps up to (and including) `make install`, but will not actually put the files into `/opt/local`. If you can debug what you need to debug from the build directory at `port work $portname`, this will simplify things.